# Operation of NOT and Z gate on the qubit in the state $|H\rangle = a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

I have this last question for an assignment and I've been stuck on it for hours.

Pauli operators for a two-level system(qubit),
$$
\sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\sigma_z = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$\sigma_x$ is called the quantum NOT gate and $\sigma_z$ is the Z gate. We have a qubit in the state $|H \rangle = \alpha |0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$. Which state is obtained after operating with the NOT gate and which state with the Z gate? What happens if we apply operation twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, $\sigma_x |H\rangle$ is given by matrix vector multiplication:

$$\pmatrix{ 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 } \pmatrix{ \alpha\\ \beta} =\pmatrix{\beta\\\alpha} $$

The state is $\beta |0\rangle + \alpha|1\rangle$. Similar for the 2nd operation.

Why is \ket in Latex not working?

Comment: Please have a look at my response below.

Comment: You can use \rangle and \langle in combination with a | to construct a ket.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! $\alpha$ and $\beta $ are constants. Shouldn't they remain outside the matrix? For example,  in ket notations
$
|0\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}, \quad |1\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$

The operation of NOT gate on these would be something like this

$
\sigma_x |H\rangle = \alpha \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix} + \beta \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix} = \alpha \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix} + \beta \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix} = \alpha |1\rangle + \beta |0\rangle
$
Am I correct?

Comment: Its correct. I'm not a physicist and cannot answer the first equation.

Comment: $\alpha |0> = \alpha \binom{1}{0} = \binom{\alpha}{0}$